# .Net Core with Docker on EC2 tutorial problems

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core

I am working through [this](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs) tutorial and trying to install a simple ASP.Net core application on EC2 container service.  I am getting till the end but can't get my container to start.  When I type in:

```
docker run 171329494690.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ecsdemo-redisgeo:latest
```

to run the container manually I get the following errors:

```
    Project RedisGeo.ServiceModel (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project RedisGeo.ServiceInterface (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project RedisGeo (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
fail: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient[0]
      Could not connect to redis Instance at localhost:6379
fail: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient[0]
      Could not connect to redis Instance at localhost:6379
fail: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient[0]
      localhost:6379

Unhandled Exception: ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException: localhost:6379 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused 127.0.0.1:6379
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.Connect() in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/8dcfdcec54d0f21a/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 212
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.AssertConnectedSocket() in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/8dcfdcec54d0f21a/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 257
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.AssertConnectedSocket() in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/8dcfdcec54d0f21a/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 273
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.AssertServerVersionNumber() in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/8dcfdcec54d0f21a/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisNativeClient_Utils.cs:line 47
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.GetServerRole() in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/8dcfdcec54d0f21a/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs:line 1092
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResolver.CreateRedisClient(RedisEndpoint config, Boolean master) in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/8dcfdcec54d0f21a/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisResolver.cs:line 84
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisManagerPool.GetClient() in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/8dcfdcec54d0f21a/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisManagerPool.cs:line 194
   at RedisGeo.AppHost.ImportCountry(IRedisClientsManager redisManager, String countryCode) in /app/RedisGeo/AppHost.cs:line 35
   at RedisGeo.AppHost.Configure(Container container) in /app/RedisGeo/AppHost.cs:line 30
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init() in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/d09206570215629/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.cs:line 189
   at ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.UseServiceStack(IApplicationBuilder app, AppHostBase appHost) in /opt/lib/teamcity-agent/work/d09206570215629/src/ServiceStack/AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 178
   at RedisGeo.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /app/RedisGeo/Startup.cs:line 27
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at RedisGeo.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/RedisGeo/Program.cs:line 14
```

Any help will be appreciated, I am a newbie to AWS so please let me know if I can provide any more information.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-projectjson
COPY src /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
WORKDIR /app/RedisGeo
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS https://*:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://*:5000"]
```

When I run the following command `docker ps --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Status}} {{.Command}} {{.Ports}}"` I get the following output of currently running docker containers

```
8285b5479401: Up 22 hours "/agent"
ba110a5f14ef: Up 46 hours "/app/docker-entrypoi" 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp
```

ecsdemo-redisgeo task container definition

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue as well, I started from the same tutorial as you did and I got the same error, I appreciate if you share your solution to it if you have found any!

Comment: I haven't found a solution and have parked it for now, I'll post the solution once I get back to it, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection refused 127.0.0.1:6379
```

This error indicates that there's no Redis Server instance available on `127.0.0.1:6379`.

Make sure your task-definition.json is the same as the [ECS task-definition.json](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs#ecs-task-definitionjson) which includes the `${IMAGE_NAME}-redis` Container definition which will tell ECS to also deploy a redis-server Docker instance with your App. You can find the scripts used to deploy the redis-geo App at [redis-geo/scripts](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo/tree/master/scripts).

The host name for the redis server instance is accessible from the [REDIS_HOST Environment Variable](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo/blob/c5f9b39e833d11c6f35d4a75a4cd5390d2419e75/scripts/task-definition.json#L29-L30) which you should [use in your App](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo/blob/c5f9b39e833d11c6f35d4a75a4cd5390d2419e75/src/RedisGeo/AppHost.cs#L27-L28) when it exists, e.g:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c =>
    new RedisManagerPool(AppSettings.Get("REDIS_HOST", defaultValue:"localhost")));
```

Comment: I haven't changed the task-definition. Whatever you have mentioned is all in play given the tutorial I followed. All I changed was the `deploy-envs.sh` as indicated in the tutorial.  I am bit lost, when will the `redis-server` be deployed? When I start my task or before that?

Comment: @Ruskin it's deployed together as an atomic unit with your App since it's all contained within the same task-definition.json

Comment: Exactly right :), that's what is driving my head in...why doesn't it start the redis server when my app is run? Any other logs I can provide to assist me further?

Comment: @Ruskin You can [check the list of running Docker containers](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs#view-list-of-running-docker-containers) otherwise I'd just look at starting from a clean slate and follow the guide from the start again, going through it again is a good learning experience.

Comment: I have edited my original question to include that information.  I agree that I can run through it again but I really want to improve my AWS troubleshooting skills and was hoping to take this opportunity to do that

Comment: @Ruskin you should see 4 Docker containers running, as seen in the docs, looks like you only have 2.

Comment: Hmm thanks @mythz, I gathered that but the tutorial has no further instructions on troubleshooting thus my post on SO

Comment: @Ruskin It goes through the [ECS dialogs you should be seeing](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs#inspect-aws-container-service) and tells you [how to troubleshoot a task if it's not running](http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs#problems-with-the-task-not-running). Your `docker ps` says your App and Redis Server Container isn't running. I can't tell you why that is, look at the output when trying to run the Containers manually in the troubleshooting section.

Comment: Thanks, I did that as part of the initial question and added the output to my question.  I just went through the entire tutorial again and back to to the same problem again :(

Comment: @Ruskin not sure what's the issue but it should be connecting to [REDIS_HOST Environment Variable](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo/blob/c5f9b39e833d11c6f35d4a75a4cd5390d2419e75/src/RedisGeo/AppHost.cs#L28) which should be populated with the ["${IMAGE_NAME}-redis variable](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo/blob/c5f9b39e833d11c6f35d4a75a4cd5390d2419e75/scripts/task-definition.json#L30). See if you can print out what `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_HOST")` returns to make sure the host name for Redis instance is being populated in task-definition.json

Comment: It all looks good because the task definition (as shown in the image attached) contains the correct value

Comment: Btw do I need to install Redis explicitly? Something is missing from that tutorial...or maybe I need a subscription to download `redis 3.2` from service stack?

Comment: @Ruskin Can you print out `AppSettings.Get("REDIS_HOST", defaultValue:"localhost")` in the Console so you can see the output of the host it's trying to connect to, it should be trying to connect to the `ecsdemo-redisgeo-redis` host, but your error says it's trying to connect to `localhost`. (FYI I'm from ServiceStack and you don't need any licenses for this demo), the redis-3.2 is the Docker Container containing the Redis Server, i.e. it's from redis.io not ServiceStack. The redis server instance should get installed along with your App when task-definition.json is deployed to AWS ECS.

Comment: I did `Console.WriteLine($"Redis host setting is {AppSettings.Get("REDIS_HOST", defaultValue: "localhost")}");` and the output is `Redis host setting is localhost`.  Note that hardcoding my private elastic IP address into the web.config makes the service run for longer but navigating to the URL in a browser gives me a `502 Bad Gateway (NGinx error)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136710/discussion-between-ruskin-and-mythz).

Comment: You got this output when running the Docker Container? than it means your REDIS_HOST Environment variable isn't set. It needs to return the same REDIS_HOST that's in your task-definition.json.

Comment: I have started a chat conversation with you as recommended by SO, can we continue there?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to develop the tutorial, after a couple of trial and failure eventually I managed to get it to work by just deleting the following entry from my task-definition.json file.

```
{
                    "name": "SERVICESTACK_LICENSE",
                    "value": "${SERVICESTACK_LICENSE}"
                },
```

the reason it failed was because I didn't have any entry for this in travis and I guess it couldn't read the REDIS_HOST which was there right after this.